# How to get table view index when click to radio button in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, radio-button

I am doing project in swift 4. I created `radiobutton` class in `tableview cell`. I want to get `cell index` when click to which `radio button`. Please help me.

Edit: I just added my entire code. I could not solve my problem. All of the codes are as follows. I created a radio button class and gave it a radio button feature. I tried to integrate the radio button in the tableview and get the index of the cell when the button is clicked as below, but it gave libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException error.

```
import UIKit

class TVCIsGuvenligi: UITableViewCell {

lazy var radioButtonGroup: [RadioButton] = {
    return [
        btnRadioEvet,
        btnRadioHayir,
        ]
}()

@IBOutlet var lblSoru: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblSoruAyrinti: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblEvet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblHayır: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var btnRadioEvet: RadioButton!
@IBAction func btnRadioEvet(_ sender: RadioButton)
{
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    updateRadioButton(sender)
    print("index \(indexPath)")
}

@IBOutlet var btnRadioHayir: RadioButton!
@IBAction func btnRadioHayir(_ sender: RadioButton)
{
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    updateRadioButton(sender)
    print("index \(indexPath)")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func updateRadioButton(_ sender: RadioButton){
    radioButtonGroup.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

  }

 }


ViewController.swift

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIs", for: indexPath) as! TVCIsGuvenligi

    cell.lblSoru.text = myTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblSoruAyrinti.text = myTitle[indexPath.row]

    cell.btnRadioEvet.tag = (indexPath.row)
    cell.btnRadioEvet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getter: cell.btnRadioEvet), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    print("current cell tag \(cell.btnRadioEvet.tag)")

    return cell
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //getting the index path of selected row
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    //getting the current cell from the index path
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! TVCIsGuvenligi

    //getting the text of that cell.
    let currentItem = currentCell.lblSoru.text

    print("current item \(currentItem)")
 }
```

Comment: use delegates to communicate with parent.

Comment: I get an index but I can not get an index when I just click on the radio button.

Comment: @MeltemAkpolat, you can easily get index in `didSelectRowAt` but to get index on cell button tap, you need to set tag to cell button. Refer my answer.

Comment: @Kuldeep I tried, but it did not. sender.tag is always 0.

Comment: @MeltemAkpolat, did you write this line?  `currentCell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row` in `cellForRow` delegate

Comment: @Kuldeep No, I wrote it into didSelectRowAt

Comment: @MeltemAkpolat, You need to add `currentCell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row` line in `cellForRow` delegate

Comment: @Kuldeep I tried, but I got this error : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @MeltemAkpolat, Add Your entire code in your question so we can identify what's problem.

Comment: Ok I will edit and add codes in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use,

```
currentCell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

And use this tag to get index on the radio button click